# verify does not execute in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I get error :

```
Wanted but not invoked:
iReimbursementDAO.update(
    Reimbursement{id=2, status=Pending, author=User{id=1, username='genericEmployee1', password='genericPassword', f_name null', l_name null', email null', role=Employee}, resolver=null, amount=150.0, description null,creation null, resolution null, receipt null}
);
-> at Test.testProcessPassesWhenUserIsFinanceManagerAndReimbursementExistsAndUpdateSuccessful(ReimbursementServiceTest.java:69)
```

Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
I followed steps from answer to previous post and got my test succeed for a different class. Now I tried the same steps in a second class as shown below and the test fails in one place.

```
public class ReimbursementServiceTest {

    private static IReimursementService reimbursementService;
    private static IReimbursementDAO reimbursementDAO;
    
    private Reimbursement REIMBURSEMENT_TO_PROCESS;
    private Reimbursement GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_1;
    private Optional<Reimbursement> 
      GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_2;
    private List<Reimbursement> GENERIC_ALL_PENDING_REIMBURSEMENTS;
    private User GENERIC_EMPLOYEE_1;
    private User GENERIC_FINANCE_MANAGER_1;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        
        reimbursementDAO = mock(IReimbursementDAO.class);
        reimbursementService = new ReimbursementService(reimbursementDAO);
    }
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        GENERIC_EMPLOYEE_1 = new User(1, "genericEmployee1", "genericPassword", Role.EMPLOYEE);
        GENERIC_FINANCE_MANAGER_1 = new User(1, "genericManager1", "genericPassword",                 Role.FINANCE_MANAGER);
        
        REIMBURSEMENT_TO_PROCESS = new Reimbursement(2, Status.PENDING, GENERIC_EMPLOYEE_1, null,                150.00);
        
        GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_1 = new Reimbursement(1, Status.PENDING, GENERIC_EMPLOYEE_1, null, 100.00);
        GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_2 = Optional.ofNullable(new Reimbursement(2, Status.APPROVED,                               GENERIC_EMPLOYEE_1,   GENERIC_FINANCE_MANAGER_1, 150.00));
        
        GENERIC_ALL_PENDING_REIMBURSEMENTS = new ArrayList<Reimbursement>();
        GENERIC_ALL_PENDING_REIMBURSEMENTS.add(GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_1);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testProcessPassesWhenUserIsFinanceManagerAndReimbursementExistsAndUpdateSuccessful()
    throws Exception{
        
        when(reimbursementDAO.getById(anyInt())).thenReturn(Optional.of(GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_1));
        when(reimbursementDAO.update(any())).thenReturn(GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_2);
        
        assertEquals(GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_2,
                reimbursementService.process(REIMBURSEMENT_TO_PROCESS, Status.APPROVED, 
                        
                        GENERIC_FINANCE_MANAGER_1));
        
        verify(reimbursementDAO).getById(REIMBURSEMENT_TO_PROCESS.getId());
        verify(reimbursementDAO).update(REIMBURSEMENT_TO_PROCESS);
        
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testGetReimbursementByStatusPassesWhenReimbursementsAreSuccessfullyReturned() {
        when(reimbursementDAO.getByStatus(any())).thenReturn(GENERIC_ALL_PENDING_REIMBURSEMENTS);
        
        assertEquals(GENERIC_ALL_PENDING_REIMBURSEMENTS, 
                reimbursementService.getReimbursementsByStatus(Status.PENDING));
        
        verify(reimbursementDAO).getByStatus(Status.PENDING);
    }
    }

   public class ReimbursementService implements 
    IReimursementService {
    private final IReimbursementDAO reimbDao;

    public ReimbursementService() {
        this(new ReimbursementDAO());
      }   
      public ReimbursementService(IReimbursementDAO userDAO2) {
        this.reimbDao = userDAO2;
       }
        
     @Override
     public Optional<Reimbursement> process(Reimbursement 
     unprocessedReimbursement,
            Status finalStatus, User resolver) throws Exception{
     if (!resolver.getRole().equals(Role.FINANCE_MANAGER)) {
               throw new RegistrationUnsuccessfulException(" be 
     Finance Manager ");}
    
     if(unprocessedReimbursement.getId()==0)
           {     throw new Exception(" reimbursement not found"); }
               
           
    if(unprocessedReimbursement.getStatus().equals(Status.PENDING))
        {
         Optional<Reimbursement> reimb=   
      this.reimbDao.update(unprocessedReimbursement);
               if(reimb.isPresent())  
               { return reimb; }
               else { throw new Exception("unsuccessful update");}
           }
           
            return Optional.ofNullable(null);       
       }
    @Override
    public List<Reimbursement> getReimbursementsByStatus(Status 
    status) {       
    return    reimbDao.getByStatus(status);
    }
    @Override
    public Optional<Reimbursement> getById(int id) {
        
        return reimbDao.getById(id);
    }
    }
```

Comment: I find your code really hard to follow, partly because of the way you've laid it out.  I think the best thing to do would be to put a breakpoint in the `process` method and run the test with your debugger.  Step through and find out whether or not the `update` method really gets called.  I believe it probably isn't getting called, maybe for some reason to do with your data.  Mockito is just telling you that `update` didn't get called, and in my experience, Mockito is usually right about these things.

Answer (score 0):

You are told what the error is: Wanted but not invoked - You WANTED to have `dao.update` invoked, but you didn't invoke it. "Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock." exactly, so why are you verifying that the update is called?

Remove this from the test `verify(reimbursementDAO).update(REIMBURSEMENT_TO_PROCESS);`

Comment: This answer misses the point of the question.  OP wants to know why Mockito says that the `update` method wasn't called.  Telling Mockito not to check won't fix the issue.

Comment: thanks Blaz and Dawood. The test fails at verify(reimbursementDAO).getById(REIMBURSEMENT_TO_PROCESS.getId()) ( wanted but was not invoked)   ; if I comment this out test (succeeds)

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem No. In the original post OP knew that there are no interactions with the mock (check the edit history).

Comment: @kobosh Of course. Why are you verifying that the mocks get called if you do not expect them to get called? It seems like the code is driving your tests instead of the tests driving your code.